# How to add $select programmatically in OData?

Tags: c#, odata

I am trying to filter out columns dynamically. I want to generate the `requestUri` something like this:

```
.../Odata/Product?$select=ProductId,ProductName
```

Is it even possible to do that through `ODataQueryOptions`?

Comment: According to [the `ODataQueryOptions` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnet.odata.query.odataqueryoptions?view=odata-aspnetcore-7.0), “Currently this only supports $filter, $orderby, $top, $skip, and $count.”

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to do is using Linq.

```
Context.Products.Select(_ => new { _.ProductId, _.ProductName});
```